# ASP.NET GridView CheckBox control is not selected fter navigating to another page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, checkbox

My `ASP.NET` page has a `GridView` that has a checkbox and allows paging.

My problem is that when selecting a checkbox on the 1st page and then after navigating to another page and coming back to the 1st page, check box is not checked anymore.

I have the following template defined for checkbox:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSecurityCheckID" runat="server" Checked="false" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible='<%# hasVisability((int)Eval("Status.UserID")) %>' AutoPostBack="false"></asp:CheckBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Is there is a way to configure `GridView` or CheckBox's properties or `jQuery` technique to remember if the checkbox was clicked?

Comment: when you come back to the page, the data is rebound in the grid... When check box is selected, if you have updated the respective field in your data source, it should get the updated data source on your second arrival; there is nothing wrong with ASP.Net behavior, it looks like logic issue in coding

Comment: @techspider is correct, however to build on his comment a little bit, you need to some how store that updated state (the fact that the checkbox is checked) and restore that state when the page loads again.  If you can't or don't want to send that back to your original datasource (i.e. database), then you can use something like session state to keep track of it.  But _you_ have to write that code ASP.NET will not do that for you.

Comment: On check-box checked event, store row id/ primary key in session and use stored records in RowDataBound event to find which row had been selected.

Comment: @Ankush Jain, frankly speaking, I have not done much GridView manipulations in ASP.NET yet and it is a little bit confusing how to proceed. Is there any code examples that I can look to understand how would I reference necessary controls in the code

Comment: http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/697_Persisting_CheckBox_State_While_Paging_in_GridView_Control.aspx

Comment: @Ankush Jain, I tried that example. It did not work in my case. Second time when page index is clicked, the value of checkbox is not there? And also, where is `RePopulateCheckBoxes()` method is called?